# Crosstabs with Groups on iReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create a report with some groups as shown on this image, but as you can see the columns are days so the numbers of columns are dynamics and I need to do it with crosstabs.

I've seen and tried some grouping examples on the net but none of them with crosstabs, so  i need to know if JasperReports can do this and how.

Jasper iReport forum also doesn't seem to be active

[image: Groups and Crosstabs]

Comment: hmm, probably yes, seems like a normal crosstab problem.

Comment: Except for the grouping and counting line (and i repeat , considering that rows and columns are dynamic wich is , a key feature of a crosstab) , or i'm definitively missing something.

Comment: Have you checked the the crosstab component (columns are dynamic), you can count values in columns create sub headers and rows.

Comment: I'll check it again Petter , thanks for your help.